# Путь до овладения навыками web программиста

Tags: веб-программирование

Привет, сразу задам вопрос

- Что и как надо учить, чтобы связать
     свое будущее с web-программированием?
- Какие книги читать советуете?
- Как практиковаться в своих знаниях и
     получить хоть небольшой опыт.

Comment: Подобных вопросов на этом форуме куча!! Да и в интернете много всего. Хотите стать программистом? Вам прямая дорога в университет информационных технологий. Нет возможности или возраст уже не тот? Тогда изучайте методом тыка, ищите информацию в интернете. А вот пальцы вверх врятли поставят за подобные вопросы)))

Comment: @LordySL я без модных универов и институтов стал программистом! Методом научного тыка) А возраст совсем не помеха!

Comment: @Palmervan "Нет возможности или возраст уже не тот" для университета.)))

Comment: Есть хорошие малые академии!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что и как надо учить

- Что - [языки программирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Веб-программирование)
- Как - Долго и упорно

> Какие книги читать советуете?

В зависимости от того с изучения какого языка решили начать свой путь!

> Как практиковаться в своих знаниях и
> получить хоть небольшой опыт.

Много свободного времени, желания! Садимся и: пишим, пишим, пишим говнокод! Все писали говнокод(при отсутствии времени или желания, продожают писать говнокод)! Когда пройдет определенный отрезок времени который зависит только от вас, говнокод начнет превращаться во что-то толковое(только не сам конечно, магии тут нет) и чотко работающее!

Comment: З.Ы. Не буду проводить агитаций за тот или определенный язык, какие книги читать а какими подтираться! Главное если вы стали специалистом - вы будите востребованы!